# How to design backend architecture for a worldwide application

Tags: architecture, backend

I was asked this question in an interview. The interviewer asked me to design backend architecture for a worldwide application (e.g. Yelp) and asked me the technologies I need to use.

What answers do I need to give (or aspect I need to consider) in an interview time slot (this question is expected to take around 5 to 10 minutes)? Can they be generalized to architecture design for similar applications? I found an answer [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-software-architecture-of-Yelp) but it is too much for an answer to an interview question and it is too specific to the application.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on what's meant by "worldwide application."  It could either mean "an application that *lots* of people use," or it could mean "an application that has users in many different countries."  If you were interviewing for a job as a systems architect, or systems engineer, I suppose the former may be what's intended; if you were interviewing for a programmer position, it may have been the latter.

For the former, they're looking for robustness and scalability type answers: Load balancing across multiple web and db servers; packet filtering and traffic monitoring, etc...

For the latter, they may be looking for usability and diverse interface type answers: language localization techniques, db models for handling different formats for addresses and phone numbers, etc...

Answer (score 1):

you are right, it's a very broad question for an interview and either a broad answer is expected to get a feeling about your scalability, availability, etc. skills or an interviewer wants to see how you tackle a problem when you don't have the details. In this case a good answer to such a question is your questions about the system, mostly about non functional requirements. It's very important to find out all the details about the system before making architectural decisions so if you start asking questions it means you know how to deal with such tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain more details about what kinds of questions do I need to ask (or from what aspects, directions) to narrow down the question?

Comment: When it comes to technologies you should ask about licensing restrictions, budget, team competency, scalability, availability requirements. Some tools/products might cost too much, some don't support both vertical and horizontal scalability, some don't support transaction. If we talk about solution design you should ask about functional requirements mostly, for example if the data to be stored is not structured and doesn't have sctrict format you might go with NoSQL or if you need to track each event in the system you might want to implement Event Sourcing and so on.